# Why User Instances (also known as RANU) available with SQL Server Express Edition, are NOT RECOMMENDED for hosting environments?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis, hosting, shared-hosting

Quoted from [http://blogs.msdn.com](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2008/02/22/sql-server-express-and-hosting.aspx):

> User Instances (also known as RANU) available with SQL Server Express Edition, are NOT RECOMMENDED for hosting environments.

I have a server running Server 2008 R2 Web Edition with IIS 7.5 and Sql Server 2008 R2 Express installed.

I have only 3 friends as my hosting clients. Each has a restricted Local User Account on the server.

What is the drawback of using **user instance** in production environment?

### Edit

Rather than considering the limitation in memory usage and database size that I know, let us consider the user instance only, why isn't it recommended?

Comment: @Recycle: It's just a close vote.  It will age away after a couple of days.  Nothing to worry about.

Comment: @Robert: did you have a reason to do a close vote?

Comment: I didn't close vote.  Someone else did.  It's OK, it takes 5 votes to close a question.  If there are no more close votes, this one will disappear after a couple of days.

Comment: @Robert: I am so sorry. I misunderstood your comment.

Comment: @Recycle, Robert Harvey is a moderator, so if he had voted to close this question, it would be closed.  It only takes 5 votes when it's us lesser mortals. :)     And, no I didn't vote to close, I followed a link from your meta question.

Comment: Also, to the anonymous close-voter, this is on topic for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the answer to your question comes with the definition of the RANU

[What is RANU](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2008/02/22/sql-express-behaviors-idle-time-resources-usage-auto-close-and-user-instances.aspx)

and also read the http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264564(SQL.90).aspx

The RANU starts a seperate instance Process of SQL Express for every user, so in a share enviroment with let say 30 sites that needs access to SQL, then SQL run 30 instances at the same time, that is takes as you understand a lot of recource/memory etc. Also as say in the article the first time SQL Express run for every user is make copies of all system database to create this user instance.

In a single user machine to run one process is normal, but if SQL Express starts to run many instances then you take a lot of resource, memory, and this is not easy to administrate, update etc.

In the article on the link there are more detail informations about this.

Comment: "with let say 30 sites that needs access to SQL, then SQL run 30 instances at the same time" ==> 30 SQL Server Express instances?

Comment: @Recycle yes, 30 sql server express instances, with 30 different user login, and 30 different master databases. Did your computer is xeon 4 core with 16Gb Ram Running 64Bit ? even if it is, its not recommended.

Comment: In my understanding, the SQL Server Instance is what we install on the computer using the installer provided by Microsoft. If using `User Instance = True` will install a new SQL Server Instance, I will see the SQL Server Instance when SQL Server Management Studio prompts us to login. Or the term `user instance` does not equal to `Sql Server instance`?

Comment: @Recycle Let me put this way. if the same think happens for iis, then you have to run 30 times the iis, each for every web site. Actually IIS runs one time and handle all site. non express SQL Server runs one time and handle all database.